# Sending an image from MMS to email

Tags: iphone, images, mms

(I hope this is on-topic, iPhone **is** a computer)

I'd like to use an iPhone to transfer images from an older phone to email. I've sent them to the iPhone using MMS, but I can't seem to figure out how to send an email containing these images. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Try touching and holding the image, and seeing if a "Save Photo" option appears.  Then just email it normally.

Comment: Touching it didn't help, but looking again I found an icon that pops up a 'save photo' dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, there's an icon I missed that pops up the Save Photo button.